# what's the meaning of '=?' in angularJS directive isolate scope declaration?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does the question mark after equals have special meaning? ie:

```
scope: {foo: '=?'}
```

does the above mean 'do not raise error if 'foo' cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

[Yes:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> The 'isolate' scope takes an object hash which defines a set of local scope properties derived from the parent scope. These local properties are useful for aliasing values for templates. Locals definition is a hash of local scope property to its source:
>
> `=` or `=attr` - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope
>   property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the `attr` attribute. If no `attr` name is specified then the
>   attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given
>   `<widget my-attr="parentModel">` and widget definition of `scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }`, then widget scope property `localModel` will
>   reflect the value of `parentModel` on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   `parentModel` will be reflected in `localModel` and any changes in
>   `localModel` will reflect in `parentModel`. **If the parent scope
>   property doesn't exist, it will throw a
>   NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception. You can avoid this behavior
>   using `=?` or `=?attr` in order to flag the property as optional.**

It should trigger the expected error on every digest that affects the scope property:

```
parentSet = parentGet.assign || function() {
// reset the change, or we will throw this exception on every $digest
lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentGet(parentScope);
     throw Error(NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION + attrs[attrName] +
     ' (directive: ' + newScopeDirective.name + ')');
};

//...


if (parentValue !== scope[scopeName]) {
    // we are out of sync and need to copy
    if (parentValue !== lastValue) {
        // parent changed and it has precedence
        lastValue = scope[scopeName] = parentValue;
    } else {
        // if the parent can be assigned then do so
        parentSet(parentScope, lastValue = scope[scopeName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense but why doesn't [this directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/FxyDVi5JeWyC6B8TX1fk?p=preview) throw exception. parent scope property doesn't exist and scope assignment is NOT using a '=?'

Comment: It seems to only throw the error when the value is set, like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OSpaC6sPE0hY9yAeFghr?p=preview

Comment: @cebor It's currently linked in the answer, but here is a more direct link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object

Comment: Although personally I wish it were documented in the scope section directly and not in $compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have been using angular for well over a year and never found the "=?" option on a directive. You just made my day ;-)