# Question mark in AngularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen some directive using question mark ('?') in the scope properties definition like so:

```
    app.directive('userInfo', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {prop: '=?'},
        templateUrl: 'some/template/url',
    };
```

I have looked for it and the only think i saw was this : [what's the meaning of '=?' in angularJS directive isolate scope declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447786/whats-the-meaning-of-in-angularjs-directive-isolate-scope-declaration). But it's not working the way he explains it there. I have succeeded running my application and no Exception was thrown.

Can somebody elaborate more about it?

Comment: What's the code of your application? How could we explain anything if we don't know its code?

Comment: According to the link you sent, no exception should be thrown because the question mark makes the defined scope variable 'prop' optional.

Comment: In my case i didn't use the '?' and no Exception was thrown

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you *don't* add the `?` and *don't* put a `prop` property on your element you're using the directive on, then an exception will be thrown.

Adding the `?`, marks the property as *optional*. As mentioned in the [documentation for `$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to flag the property as optional.

I think the documentation might be a bit outdated in that area. `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` only appears in [older revisions of the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ac899d0da59157fa1c6429510791b6c3103d9401/src/ng/compile.js#L807).

Please note that **the exception is only thrown once you try to write to the scope property**. I threw together a quick plunkr to showcase the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/hjUq6ZisuRG2C3mZpRDj?p=preview

Comment: Yea, I got it. that wasn't the question tough.
My problem is that when I'm not using '?' and not using the 'prop' property in element no Exception is thrown. so I thought there is a different explanation for the use of '?'

Comment: @user1857251 I updated my answer. Hopefully it's more helpful now :)

Comment: Yea, I think that the documentation is outdated to. I have tried it and as you said - when you are trying to change the value of the scope property there is an exception because its undefined (if you didn't use '?'). Thanks!