# Angular optional attribute in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive:

```
angular
  .module('test')
  .directive('multiButton', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        disabled: '@'
      },
      template: '<div class="multi-button"><button ng-disabled={{disabled}}></button></div>'
    });
```

The disabled scope attribute is optional, but I don't want to have "ng-disabled" stuff in my template when rendered if no disabled attribute was submitted.

Is this possible? And if so how?

Comment: `disabled: '@?'`, the `?` operator. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20447939/624590

Comment: @DRobinson sure but still when the template is rendered, it will have "ng-disabled" in it right? This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Ahhhh, makes sense. Then you probably want the `@?` combined with a `compile` function to build the template String.

Comment: @randomKek are you going to set the `disabled` value dynamically

Comment: Actually, compile was over-complicating things. Link makes more sense. Updated my answer to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the attribute exists on link, and add the related (`ngDisabled`) attribute if so:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .directive('multiButton', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                disabled: '@?'
            },
            template: '<div class="multi-button"><button></button></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attr){
                if(attr.disabled){
                    element.find('button').attr('ng-disabled', attr.disabled);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guv11rxq/

Now, as expected, `<multi-button disabled="hello"></multi-button>` will result in:

`<div class="multi-button"><button ng-disabled="hello"></button></div>`

But without the optional attribute, `<multi-button></multi-button>`, it will result in:

`<div class="multi-button"><button></button></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `ng-if` in your template:

```
 template: '<div class="multi-button" ng-if="disabled != ''"><button ng-disabled={{disabled}}></button></div><div class="multi-button" ng-if="disabled === ''"><button></button></div>'
```

Comment: This adds a lot of extra template code to maintain (any changes have to be made in both places, which should often be avoided when writing code - aim for DRY). Also, and this is a a much smaller issue, it will add two comparisons to every `$digest` cycle for every one of these elements.

Comment: @DRobinson You are correct. This is not the best way to do this, but you can use it nevertheless.

Comment: Yep, I agree that in principle this basically works, albeit very non-optimal. This is an approach that should be avoided for the reasons that I outlined in the comment above.