# AngularJS : What is the usage of '=?' in scope of angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have seen developers using '=?' in angular scope for a directive. Can someone please explain me its usage.

Comment: it is use for two way binding

Comment: this is example link https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: The `=?` means optional two way binding. Without the `?` if you didn't provide an attribute in the DOM it would throw an exception.

Comment: so ? can be given to any other directive scope? ex:- '@?' and '&?'

Comment: @ste2425 can you provide the documentation/source for your answer?

Comment: no it wont provide and exeption

Comment: @Ahmer An exception will be thrown, however i was wrong in explaining the circumstances to cause it, see Goldenowner's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> `=` or `=attr` - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the `attr` attribute. If no `attr` name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<widget my-attr="parentModel">` and widget definition of `scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }`, then widget scope property `localModel` will reflect the value of `parentModel` on the parent scope. Any changes to `parentModel` will be reflected in `localModel` and any changes in `localModel` will reflect in `parentModel`. If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a **NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION** exception. You can avoid this behavior using `=?` or `=?attr` in order to flag the property as optional. If you want to shallow watch for changes (i.e. $watchCollection instead of $watch) you can use `=*` or `=*attr` (`=*?` or `=*?attr` if the property is optional).

**[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)** (CTRL+F, "=?")

Comment: I was trying to replicate the exception, but I donot see an error being thrown. Instead the value set is just null.
[JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/shashikant/4jy2px3k/)

Comment: Here is an example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SakSg6x5wuQQ5eYBwFN?p=preview) where you get the `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` error.

Comment: according to your example, if I add selectModel: "=?" in child1 directive scope, it should still work. Correct?

Comment: @Shashi 1). It's not my example, I just quickly googled the error and gave you the first example with that error. 2). I only gave you the information that Angular has about it. - This `=?` expression is new for me too, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: @Shashi I've found another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447786/whats-the-meaning-of-in-angularjs-directive-isolate-scope-declaration) with a lot of information about `=?`, hope that answers your question a bit more.